# iPhone 4 has 3G connectivity but can't access internet

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

Just last week, my access to the internet over mobile data networks has stopped working. I've already talked to my operator, and they gave me a new SIM card and tested that 3G works in another phone with it.

Basically the operator is expecting this to be an antenna failure, which seems odd as I still get full connection bars, WiFi works flawlessly and my 3G does transport e-mails, just nothing else (like opening websites).

I do have 21M/2M speed, so the connection isn't just clogged.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

If nothing comes up, I will probably have to get a new antenna and install it myself.

I've discovered that SSH connections are working on 3G. This is becoming really weird...

Comment: For some time I exerienced the same problem, but it was solved by changing the SIM card. It does not sound like a software problem but have you tried resetting your phone and installing the latest iOS update?

Comment: I should try a reset, good idea :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Settings -> General -> VPN (should be not connected, if this is a personal device)
2. Settings -> General -> Cellular -> Cellular Data (turn off, reset the device)
3. After the device boot-up
4. Settings -> General -> Cellular -> Cellular Data (turn on, reset the device)

IF that doesn't help (follow this )

1. Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings (this will delete all Wi-Fi passwords)
2. Settings -> General -> Safari -> Clear History -> Clear History
3. Settings -> General -> Safari -> Clear Cookies and Data -> Clear Cookies and Data
4. Settings -> General -> Safari -> Advanced -> Website Data -> Remove All Website Data -> Remove Now (** All data saved in Safari will be deleted)
5. Reset the  device

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the phone is able to receive emails is kind of suspicious; maybe that could indicate that there's some problem with your DNS configuration.

You should try to enter Google's ip directly into safari instead of the URI (173.194.41.8 as of my location, YMMV). If that works, there's a problem with your network provider's settings.

Comment: I checked the IP for Google here and tried to connect to that, but it still can't open the page. "Server stopped responding"

Comment: Have you tried to reset network settings?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace your antenna that is going to be a very difficult task to complete. don't do it if you're not comfortable taking apart your iPhone. I think the antenna should be less than $30 on amazon now though.

The antenna is in the base of the phone. The area where you plug it in, there's a small black component which houses the plug interface and the antenna is wrapped around this. Water damage or trauma to this area may have caused the failure you're experiencing but your intermittent issues are confusing.

I'm not sure what this may or may not tell you, but put your phone in Field Test mode by dialing  `*3001#12345#*` which will give you some legit statistics on your connection. Your bars in the top left will be replaced with your actual signal rating in digits.

[more info on field test mode](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/20/field-test-mode-iphone-signal-strength-numbers/)

[more info on the antenna repair](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+iPhone+4+Cellular+Antenna/4359/1)

Answer (score 1):

Turn airplane mode on from Settings or Control Center, wait three seconds, and then turn off again.

Comment: This is the fastest, cleanest solution.

Comment: Hard to verify this method, since this was solved 6 months ago already..

Answer (score 0):

Turn the airplane mode off and turn off phone and on again, go to internet "safari" It will ask to turn off airplane mode, hit ok, and voila, it's all good. 
Had trouble after upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

I had to turn off my "LTE" it was preventing me from getting a connection...I am on 4G now and everything is fine

Comment: This is really uninformative and not even a good solution, since I don't want to limit my phone