# iPhone 4s not connecting to the Internet using the sim and heating up in standby

Tags: iphone

I purchased an iPhone 4s on eBay. The phone is as if permanently locked in 'Searching... ' mode (the top left hand corner of the display). The phone is not connecting to the Internet, or the WiFi, and neither does it seem to connect to phone services through the SIM card inserted. And while the phone is in this state, it is heating up on the right-hand side, with display facing upwards, and gets drained of battery in about 40 minutes, even when it is in standby mode.

I have replaced the battery, and then the antenna, but to no avail.

What could be the problem? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The next things to replaced once you've replaced the antenna and the battery are to double check the wires and connection points and then replace the logic board which contains both the cellular chip and the firmware/software to run that part of the system.

Field test mode might also let you know what signal levels are being reported/measured and compare them with other iPhone 4S if you have them handy.

- [iPhone 4 has 3G connectivity but can't access internet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93077/iphone-4-has-3g-connectivity-but-cant-access-internet)
- [iPhone field test instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99301/iphone-field-test-instructions)